# shift position of the content in an ImageView (mobile data type, e.g. 'LTE' or 'H') programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Ryebread761's idea of [rotating the Wifi signal](https://github.com/rye761/upsidewifi/blob/master/src/ryebread761/upsidewifi/UpsideWifi.java) icon is genius! (for the uninitiated, it uses an Xposed module to hook the layout call from SystemUI and rotate the Wifi signal icon before drawing.)

[image: empty description]

So I'm replicating this for the Cell Signal strength. Since we're the one receiving the signal strength from the tower, the POV should reflect this, like the Wifi icon does after Ryebread's mod.

As far as I can tell all I can do is rotate/mirror images. That works fine for this:

[image]

which turns into this

[image]

but not for this:

[image]

because when I rotate it, it's upside down.

### **What I would like, is to arrive at this, programmatically:**

[image]

### without having to provide a new SystemUI.apk for the user to flash.

Please note that using [setPadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) looks like it's causing the ImageView to scale down/get smaller/or something!

Comment: Did you try the setTranslationX() and setTranslationY() methods of the view?

Comment: @Devunwired no sir. wouldn't that just change it relative to mobile_combo? IE little different from using setPadding https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-12.0/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/signal_cluster_view.xml#L100

Comment: It would shift it relative to its parent, usually the bars/text are two views in the same parent container. Adding padding keeps the view the same size/location, just reduces the amount of usable area you have inside to draw (which is why it shrinks). Translate actually moves the view in question.

Comment: OHHHH thank you that works!!! please make answer. @Devunwired

Comment: where can I read more about the intricacies of this? I understand how it happens, I do not understand why they decided to allow drawing outside a parent container. Seems like could lead to problems. @Devunwired

Comment: The drawing ought to still be clipped to the parent container. The container is roughly the size of the larger (signal bars) image. Any portion of the view that does outside that bound should be clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to translate the `ImageView` instead of rotate it, use the `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY()` view property methods.

Comment: *pad it. translate instead of padding it. For future folks, key applicable tacit knowledge: padding inserts new content and scales to stay within parent container, translate shifts/moves it and truncates like drag/drop behaves near the edge of canvas in PaintXP. API description so much more obfuscated...